# Why you cannot skip lines during debugging of Java application

Tags: java, debugging

While debugging my Android application I wanted to jump over (skip) part of the code that is causing exceptions, but is it in the middle of a method implementation.
After failing to find something useful from the menus, I decided to look into stackoverflow and I just found that there is no way to do exactly this - you can comment out code, add some 'skip' variables that you can set to true during debugging and that code will be skipped. However, in my previous experience with C, skipping part of the code was feature supported by all of the debuggers I have used, and I think that in general it was changing the program counter to point to the new line that I want to be executed.

Obviously this is not possible in Java, but I couldn't find anywhere an answer why it is not possible.
So can someone elaborate on this?

Comment: This is not quite what you are looking for but if you are using Eclipse you can highlight the code you wish to execute and do `Ctrl`+`U` to execute it.

Answer (score 1):

I can assume that it is because java does not have neither `goto` nor `jump` operations. I believe that C debuggers use one of these operators in their implementation.

The question is why java does not support `goto` or `jump`. Beyond the fact that these operations break structural programming paradigm I can assume that they also break java threads synchronization mechanism.

This is my opinion only that is not based on deep investigation but on feelings only.

Comment: When an exception occurs, wouldn't java still use something like goto, to skip code?

Comment: No, exception is different. It jumps to the point that called method that threw exception. There is a difference between this and jumping to any random address.